# Determinar destino de un PDF generado

Tags: php, html, pdf, mpdf

Buenas comunidad, solicito su ayuda nuevamente, esta vez es sobre la generación de un documento **PDF** con la librería **mPDF**.

***La consulta es la siguiente:*** ¿Como hago para determinar el destino de mi **PDF** generado? Es decir, se que cuando se genera el documento se da la opción al usuario de guardar o abrir, pero independientemente de estas opciones quiero guardarlo yo en ua carpeta en específico al ser generado. Sería algo como 2 documentos, uno que yo guardo a travez del código, y otro que el usuario decide si abrirlo o guardarlo. Aquí les dejo porción de mi codigo por si sirve de algo. Gracias de antemano.

```
$mpdf = new mPDF('c', 'A5');$css= file_get_contents("recursos/estilos/estilo_reporte.css");
$mpdf->WriteHTML($css,1);
$mpdf->writeHTML($HTML,2);
$mpdf->Output('Reporte.pdf','I');
```

Comment: @LuisFernando no es un posible duplicado , la pregunta corresponde a SOen  y esto es SOes .

Comment: Vale, disculpenme esa. Pero en mi defensa a la hora de crear el titulo no me apareció esa referencia, y estuve muy pendiente, pero vale, muchas gracias, revisaré un poco mas esa pregunta tambien aunque ya me ayudaron a resolver el problema. Pueden realizar las operaciones correspondientes para cerrar el tema.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes usar dos métodos `Output`, uno para guardarlo dentro de tu servidor y otro para mostrarlo en el navegador, ejemplo:

```
$mpdf = new mPDF('c', 'A5');$css= file_get_contents("recursos/estilos/estilo_reporte.css");
$mpdf->WriteHTML($css,1);
$mpdf->writeHTML($HTML,2);
$mpdf->Output('/ruta/para/guardar/tu/Reporte.pdf', 'F'); //guarda a ruta
$mpdf->Output('Reporte.pdf','I'); //muestra a usuario
//$mpdf->Output('Reporte.pdf','D'); //descargar directamente
```

puedes usar dos botones html, uno para mostrar y otro para guardar en el servidor y/o descargar el pdf con el código anterior.

Comment: ¿Puedes explicarme que debería pasar al ejecutar este código? Porque lo acabo de probar y ok, me apareció la ventana para guardar o abrir, pero  ¿como determino yo una "copia" para guardarla donde yo quiera?

Comment: dentro del codigo puse `$mpdf->Output('/ruta/para/guardar/tu/Reporte.pdf', 'F');` debes cambiarlo por una ruta dentro de tu servidor

Comment: Muchas gracias, me ha servido. Algo parecido hay en la pregunta que me dicen que está duplicada. Ya se puede cerrar el tema.